# Possible to changes assumed file extension for VS Code R

Tags: r, windows, visual-studio-code

Suppose we create a new R file in VS code (with R extension) and try to "Save As", the "Save as type" option for me defaults to

> R (*.r,*.rhistory,*.rprofile,*.rt,*.R)

And so saving the file defaults to the first extension, say "script.r" instead of "script.R".

Tried changing the file(s) associated with R hoping if `.r` is not recognised then it would default to `.R` but no luck

I don't have enough knowledge of Windows / VS code to understand where it gets "R (*.r,*.rhistory,*.rprofile,*.rt,*.R)" from or how to change this.

---

Is there any way to change this in VS code settings?

Alternatively, can we change default file extensions via Windows settings?

Comment: what happens if you change the order of the extensions mentioned in the R language extension for the r-languageID

Comment: I am unable to change the order of the extensions. The order is not a VS code setting but something that shows up in the windows save file context menu.

Also: I am unsure why it is different for VS code compared to RStudio say.

Comment: the file extensions are based on the extensions named in the language json file, VSC/Node fills the fields of the OpenFile dialog